# Debian Installer "Install the base system" failed "Couldn't download package apt"

Tags: debian-installer

I am setting up debian on an old machine to use as a home fileserver and am having issues installing. I hooked up the network over Ethernet using my laptop's network share and I think the connection is working (is there a way to test this in the installer?) but the installer freezes on "Retrieving apt" and then fails about a minute later.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Quit the installer, but leave the live disk running.  Open a terminal, and type `sudo ping -c4 debian.org`  Also, what version are you attempting to install/?

Comment: You should be able to use a terminal without quitting the installer by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or is it F2? I don't know which one the installer is using itself). Also, on Ctrl+Alt+F4 should be a debug log that hopefully contains additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different Internet access.

Debian uses http & ftp mirrors.

FTP is the "classical" problematic-to-NAT protocol.

Hence, "network sharing" usually implies a NAT, because the machine sharing the connection has exactly one IP itself.

Comment: So it would probably be a better idea to plug this into my router via ethernet then see if the install works?

Comment: @joeelectricity In my experience, it's always preferable to install over ethernet. You don't always have all the device drivers necessary for other network interfaces during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem, at least in my case, was to check integrity of the downloaded ISO file.

In addition to that check integrity of the image when booted, there is an option in the installer when booted.

If the integrity test fails your image is corrupted and should be downloaded again.